# Speed of pandas df.loc[x, 'column']

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame of about 100 rows, from which I need to select values from a column for a given index in an efficient way. At the moment I am using `df.loc[index, 'col']` for this, but this seems to be relatively slow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(100)}, index=range(100))    
%timeit df.loc[random.randint(0, 99), 'col']
#100000 loops, best of 3: 19.3 µs per loop
```

What seems to be much faster (by a factor of about 10x) is to turn the data frame into a dictionary and then query that:

```
d = df.to_dict()    
%timeit d['col'][random.randint(0, 99)]
#100000 loops, best of 3: 2.5 µs per loop
```

Is there a way to get similar performance using normal data frame methods, without explicitly creating the dict? Should I be using something other than `.loc`?

Or is this just a situation where I am better off using this workaround?

Comment: Here are a couple of alternatives: `df.get_value(random.randint(0, 99), 'col')` (fastest), `df['col'].values[random.randint(0, 99)]` (assumes positions and labels are the same) and `df.at[random.randint(0, 99), 'col']`  but this part is generally not the part you should  focus on while doing code optimization. Probably you are doing this inside a loop, right?

Comment: Agree with @ayhan, pure Python dictionaries will almost certainly be faster than Pandas methods for reading a scalar value by index, since Pandas methods are heavily overloaded, and each contain multiple dictionary accesses. The biggest potential for performance improvement lies in using vectorized functions instead of Python loops.

Comment: Unfortunately, vectorisation isn't really an option here, since I need to process a file line by line and can't keep all the data in memory. Switching from `.loc` to a `dict` does seem to lead to roughly a 5-10x speedup of the entire loop in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dict` does indeed seem to be the fastest option:

```
df_dict = df.to_dict()
df_numpy = np.array(df)
print(timeit.timeit("df.loc[random.randint(0, 99), 'col']", number = 100000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit("df.get_value(random.randint(0, 99), 'col')", number = 100000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit('df_numpy[df_numpy[random.randint(0, 99)]]', number=100000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit("df_dict['col'][random.randint(0, 99)]", number = 100000, globals=globals()))
```

Result:

```
4.859706375747919
1.8850274719297886
1.4855970665812492
0.6550335008651018
```

Answer (score 0):

If efficient is a factor to consider, Numpy arrays could be a better choice than pandas dataframe. I try to reproduce your example for measure the efficiency comparison:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit, random

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(100)}, index=range(100)) 
print(timeit.timeit('df.loc[random.randint(0, 99), "col"]', number=10000, globals=globals()))

ds_numpy = np.array(df)
print(timeit.timeit('ds_numpy[ds_numpy[random.randint(0, 99)]]', number=10000, globals=globals()))
```

Results:

```
$ python test_pandas_vs_numpy.py 
0.1583892970229499
0.05918855100753717
```

In this scenario it looks like than use Numpy array over pandas dataframe is and advantage in terms of performance.

Reference: [1](http://machinelearningexp.com/data-science-performance-of-python-vs-pandas-vs-numpy/)

Comment: Thanks - while this is an improvement over .loc, it still seems to be significantly slower than using the dictionary (approx 2-3x).